# Adding a PayPal coupon code to final price

Tags: paypal, coupon, promotion-code

I looking to add promo codes to my PayPal shoppingcart.
I have 80+ products, each with their own PayPal button, so I am not interested in generating new buttons for every item.
Is there a way where the users can add a promo code at the final step to subtract a percentage of the price?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There is a discount_amount parameter you can include with your button, but if you're not generating the button code dynamically and actually have separate, static code for every product, then you won't really have an easy way to implement it.  There isn't any way to tie that into the checkout without adding it to your button...at least not when using PayPal's cart like that.

What I would recommend is in the very least dynamically generating your product button code so you could easily add things like this.  You'd have to change 1 piece of code instead of 80+.

An even better way is to go ahead and build a shopping cart directly into your site.  Then you'll have discount codes and a lot more built in by default.  I'd recommend WordPress + WooCommerce.  I bet you'd love it.